# get exception type in python 1.5.2

Tags: python, exception, syntax-error, raise

How can I get the type of an Exception in python 1.5.2?

doing this:

```
try:
    raise "ABC"
except Exception as e:
    print str(e)
```

gives an SyntaxError:

```
  except Exception as e:
                    ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**EDIT:**
this does not work:

```
try:
    a = 3
    b = not_existent_variable
except Exception, e:
    print "The error is: " + str(e) + "\n"

a = 3
b = not_existent_variable
```

as I only get the argument, not the actual error (NameError):

```
The error is: not_existent_variable

Traceback (innermost last):
  File "C:\Users\jruegg\Desktop\test.py", line 8, in ?
    b = not_existent_variable
NameError: not_existent_variable
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's

```
except Exception, e:
```

In Python 1 and 2. (Although `as` also works in Python 2.6 and 2.7).

(Why on earth are you using 1.5.2!?)

To then get the type of the error you use `type(e)`. To get the type name in Python 2 you use `type(e).__name__`, I have no idea if that works in 1.5.2, you'll have to check the docs.

Update: It didn't, but `e.__class__.__name__` did.

Comment: Perhaps he's using it on the Palm Pilot where development stopped at 1.5.2... And my upvote is now pushing you over the 10k barrier - congratulations!

Comment: Use your new powers wisely, young Padawan. :)

Comment: Something like that... I'm working on a telit gsm module (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/CellularDevTelitGSMPython.aspx), and 1.5.2 is in hardware. However, your solution does not seem to work... (see my edit)

Comment: @Jan Rüegg: Updated with how to get the type. str(e) will convert it to a string, and that does not include the Type name for that exception.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro: I tried that... but the type of "e" (and its name) is "instance", and its only method is "args" which returns ('not_existent_variable',). I can't find anything about that in the documentation...

Comment: Ah, right, of course, it's an old-style class in 1.5.2. Try `e.__class__.__name__`.